# Are all of the implicit type conversions that happen in JavaScript considered to be type coercion?

Tags: javascript

Say we have the following:

```
2 + "2"            // 2 will be converted to string

5 + true           // true will be converted to number

5 + new Number(1)  // new Number(1) (which is a Number) will be converted to number

"hello".length     // "hello" (which is a string) will be converted to String
```

All of the above examples involves implicit type conversions, but do all of the above examples considered to be type coercion, or only some of them considered to be type coercion?

More specifically, are all of the implicit type conversions that happen in JavaScript (and not just the ones that I showed in the above examples) considered to be type coercion?

Comment: Short answer: yes

Comment: For me, what's confusing about this question to me is that it asks if every instance of a _specific_ case is a member of the _general case_ **to which it belongs by definition**.  It's like asking "are all minivans considered to be vans" or "are all compact cars considered to be cars"-- the wording is such that I'm struggling to understand why it would _not_ be the case...

Comment: @Alexander Nied The reason why I asked this question is because all of the tutorials that I have seen on type coercion in JavaScript don't mention examples such as `5 + new Number(1)` or `"hello".length`, so I thought that maybe JavaScript have its own definition of type coercion that only applies to specific cases of implicit type conversions.

Comment: Interesting.  For what it is worth, I'd recommend against getting "clever" with implicit type conversions in JS-- they can be difficult to read and yield unintuitive results.  I generally explicitly cast to a type when indicated.

Comment: @Steven You won't find `new Number` in any tutorials because its usage is discouraged, and the object coercion in accessing properties on primitives is generally considered an unimportant detail that few will care about. You can see what `"hello".length` does without understanding all the details of how `String.prototype` is (not) involved in that.

Answer (score 2):

Given [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)

> In most languages, the word *coercion* is used to denote an *implicit* conversion

the answer is clearly **yes**.

<sup>(And JavaScript is no exception, it doesn't officially define the term any different, or at all)</sup>